# Dynamically changing a list while looping

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list:

```py
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

what I would like to do is loop though this list but then change the list. Basically when I loop through `nums = [0, 1, 2, 3]` nums would need to change to:

```py
nums = [current_element, 0, 1, 2]
nums = [0, current_element, 1, 2]
nums = [0, 1, current_element, 2]
nums = [0, 1, 2, current_element]
```

Is there a way of changing `nums` like this? I feel like there is a simple solution to this, but I've been stumped for hours.

Comment: It'd be handy if you explained the logic behind this... it's not clear what `current_element` is supposed to be or why you want the list changed... ?

Comment: I also do not understand where this is going, the final answer miss explicit the whole point of "change the list" and current_element can be written like a variable(!?) so is the question ambiguous or the answer wrong? I think it is first cause otherwise you could simply change nums[i] and nums[i+1] with for i in range(len(nums)-1)?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `map()` object to the `for` loop that generates the list you need at each iteration. For each index, we generate a new list using list slicing to replace the element at that index:

```py
current_element = 42
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for lst in map(lambda x: nums[:x] + [current_element] + nums[x+1:], range(len(nums))):
    print(lst)
```

This outputs:

```py
[42, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 42, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 42, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 42]
```

This approach has two notable advantages:

1. This doesn't mutate the original list. If you need to access the original list for any reason, you can.
2. You don't need to worry about resetting values at the start/end of each iteration. If you need to implement this pattern several times, you don't need to remember to replace the values each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a simple solution.

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    nums[i] = current_element
    do_processing(nums)
    nums[i] = i
```

The other way, of course, is just to make a copy of the list.

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
    n1 = nums[:]
    n1[i] = current_element
    do_processing(n1)
```

Answer (score 0):

No fancy functions, just a for loop and a temporary variable.

```
for i in range(len(nums)):
  old_value = nums[i]
  nums[i] = current_element
  ...
  nums[i] = old_value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums.pop()
for i in range(len(nums)+1):
  nums.insert(i,current_element)
  print(nums)
  nums.remove(current_element)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.